# Reference cells from column a where column b is atleast (value)

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a formula that can get me the reference of cells in "Column A" if "Column B" >= 2.

i.e.

```
 Column A   Column B
 Company 1    1
 Company 2    1
 Company 3    3
 Company 4    1
 Company 5    5
 Company 6    4
```

So in this example the output would be

```
 Column A
 Company 3
 Company 5
 Company 6
```

I am a bit confused on how to approach this, can you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Um... `=IF(B1>=2,A1,)` and drag down... _can't be that simple_

Answer (score 0):

Both these answers use an array formula, so enter with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` in first cell and drag down.

If your list starts on row 1 you can use:
`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$6>=2,ROW($B$1:$B$6),""),ROW(B1))),"")}`

Otherwise use (this is for rows 10:15):
`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$10:$A$15,SMALL(IF($B$10:$B$15>=2,ROW($B$10:$B$15)-MIN(ROW($B$10:$B$15))+1,""),ROW(B1))),"")}`